# Why do I get 'undefined' when using let keyword in comparison to var

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand both **let** and **var** keywords. It is not clear for me why do I get **'undefined'** when I use let keyword?

```js
let currentScope = 'global';
function print() {
    let currentScope = 'local';
    console.log(this.currentScope); //undefined
    console.log(currentScope);     //local
}

print();
console.log(currentScope);  //global
```

**and here I use var**

```js
var currentScope = 'global';
function print() {
    var currentScope = 'local';
    console.log(this.currentScope); //global
    console.log(currentScope); //local
}

print();
console.log(currentScope); //global
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `this` at all here. In strict mode, the code will fail (rightfully)

Comment: It comes down to what `this` is and that it does not have a `currentScope` property.

Comment: Because `this` refers to `window` and using `var` it's registered on window object

Comment: I did to learn because I noticed 'this' works with var, in this example? @Bergi

Comment: No, "this works with var" is not a rule you should learn. Use `globalThis.currentScope` or `window.currentScope` (inside and outside of the function), and make the connection to the global variable declaration. In fact is has nothing to do with the function at all.